# Daisy-Chain methods from reflection on DbContext .NET

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection

My problem is, I want to call `.OrderBy()` and multiple `.ThenBy()` depending on the objects in a list.

So for 4 objects it would be:

```
db.Entity.Where(lambda expression).OrderBy(lambda from object1).ThenBy(lambda from object2).ThenBy(lambda from object3).ThenBy(lambda from object4).
```

How do I call the equivalent of the above method by reflection from a loop?

I would most likely have to do this by reflection... something like:

```
foreach(var sortLambda in sortLambdaList)
{
  //Build expression to build daisy-chain method call

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you provide some code sample of what the four classes look like? Its not clean if there are four different instances of the same class or four different classes in db.Entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be made slicker, but the general idea would be.

```
var query = db.Entity.Where(lambda expression);
var first = true; 
foreach(var sortLambda in sortLambdaList)
{
    if (first) {
        query = query.OrderBy(sortLambda);
    } else {
        first = false; 
        query = query.ThenBy(sortLamda);
    }
}
```

Comment: var query = db.Set<entityModel>().AsQueryable(); works too!